# Angular2 Components - Dynamic Inline Styles

Tags: javascript, css, angular, components

I have a component that has a `count` and a `color` property. The component is supposed to display `count` number of `<div>`s with an inline style used to change its color to `color`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-control',
    template: `<div *ngFor="let i of dummyArray" style="color: {{color}}"> COLOR = {{color}}</div>`
})
export class MyControl {
    private _count: number;
    @Input() set count(value: string) {
        this._count = +value;
    }
    @Input() set color(value: string) {
        this._color = value;
    }
    get dummyArray(): number[] {
        let ret: number = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this._count; ++i) ret.push(i);
        return ret;
    }
    get color(): string {
        return this._color;
    }
}
```

This renders:

```
<my-control count="5" color="red">
    <div>COLOR = red</div>
    <div>COLOR = red</div>
    <div>COLOR = red</div>
    <div>COLOR = red</div>
    <div>COLOR = red</div>
</my-control>
```

Now I have two issues with this:

1. Is there any better way to render the `<div>`s `count` times without creating a dummy array?
2. More importantly, the inline styles are not being set. If I hardcode styles like `style="color: red"`, it works. But `style="color: {{color}}"` does not. The element is rendered without any styles as you can see above.

For #2, I have also tried using the `nativeElement`'s children as well:

```
@Input() set count(value: string) {
    this._count = +value;
    this.update();
}
@Input() set color(value: string) {
    this._color = value;
    this.update();
}
update(): void {
    for (let i = 0; i < this._count; ++i) {
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement.children[i], 'color', this._color);
    }
}
```

But I get exception accessing the child elements as they don't exist apparently.

How should I go about solving these issues?

Comment: There is no way to us `ngFor` without an array. You could create your custom `ngFor` directive that does that. There is an issue to support `ngFor` with a number instead of an array but it's unlikely to be implemented.

Comment: thanks for the tip mate.. this sucks though.. makes for a clumsy implementation of components in such cases..

Comment: Your code can be optimized a bit. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535629/repeat-html-element-multiple-times-using-ngfor-based-on-a-number

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer.. love it!.. this is a lot more elegant than what i have at present.. thanks for the tip.. =)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
<div *ngFor="let i of dummyArray" style="color: {{color}}>
```

is missing the closing `"` after `color}}`

Binding this way to style should be avoided because it doesn't work in all Safari versions (maybe also others).

Instead use

```
<div *ngFor="let i of dummyArray" [ngStyle]="{'color': color}">
```

Comment: apologies.. i missed the ending `"` accidentally here.. the issue still remains.. let me check the `[ngStyle]="{'color': color}"` thingy and report back..

Comment: this is the fastest ive ever gotten an answer.. im counting minutes to be able to mark this as the correct answer.. =)

Comment: now i have an additional question, if you can take out time for this one.. i lose all css animations if i use *ngFor.. is there a way around it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "loose". There are some known issues how `ngFor` treats changes in the array that don't work well with animation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217314/how-can-i-animate-ngfor-in-angular-2/37217476#37217476

Answer (score 3):

About your first question:

To create an array with ten `undefined` elements, you could do:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div *ngFor="let i of arr(10); let index=index">hello {{index}}</div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  arr=Array;
}
```

[check this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/I9LtJM31Sa21Py9t6K5S?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for the tip mate.. unfortunately i can only accept one answer as the correct answer.. And Gunter's is more correct as it answers the more pressing issue.. =(

Comment: You are welcome @AweSIM. I totally agree Gunter's answer is the correct one. Also, the blasting speed of his answer has to be counted  :) . It just that I had an addition to his answer and posted it. And now I see that he already commented on your question in relation to the issue I answered :D