# Does ngFor directive re-render whole array on every mutation?

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

Let's say we have an array of items:

```
items = [
    { title: 'item 1'},
    { title: 'item 2'},
    /* ... */
];
```

And there is a template that renders this array:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

Wll angular2 rerender the whole array if I add/remove items via `push`/`splice` or will it only add/remove the markup for the corresponding items? If it does updates only, then is there any difference in mutation stategies -- should I prefer push/splice over array replacing? In other words, are these two approaches equivalent in term of rendering performance:

```
/* 1: mutation */
this.items.push({ title: 'New Item' });

/* 2: replacement */
var newArray = this.items.slice();
newArray.push({ title: 'New Item' });

this.items = newArray;
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No <strike>, it re-renders only when the array itself is replaced by a different array instance.</strike>

**update**

Thanks to Olivier Boissé (see comments)

Even when a different array instance is passed, Angular recognizes if it contains the same item instances and doesn't rerender even then.

See also this [**StackBlitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-veoqsm)

If the used `IterableDiffer` recognizes and addition or removal at the beginning or in the middle, then an item is inserted/removed at that place without re-rendering all other items.

The animations demonstrated in Plunkers in answers of this question [How can I animate *ngFor in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217314/how-can-i-animate-ngfor-in-angular-2) also demonstrate that. In fact this kind of animation was a driving factor to get this implemented this way (in addition to general optimization)

Comment: Angular doesn't re-renders the elements that were present in the previous array instance.

Comment: @OlivierBoissé that's what my answer tries to say. When the array instance is replaced by a different one with the same content, I'm pretty sure it will completely re-render, otherwise, as you said, it will render only added items and keep the DOM elements for the ones that were in the array previously.

Comment: event with a new instance it's not completely re-render, I tested it by exloring the DOM, I have a **new** array and the items are not re-rendered because they were alredy there in the previous one

Comment: @OlivierBoissé you don't have by any chance a http://stackblitz.com example to reproduce?

Comment: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dncqm2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dncqm2), inspect the first two `<p>` you will see they are not re-render

Comment: @OlivierBoissé thanks a lot. Seems `IterableDiffer` was improved even more since I last tried. I added some CSS animation to the example you provided to make it more obvious.

Comment: I think Angular compares with the `===` operator, because if I replace the existing ones by new objects (with the same properties/values), the items are re-rendered

Comment: For the items definitely object identity is used. Angular change detection never cares about object content (except when directly bound to a property). `*ngFor` doesn't depend on change detection alone, because it uses the `IterableDiffer` to find changes inside an object (array), but it also only checks object identity of the items in the array, not their properties or values.

Comment: Does this mean you do not need to bother about using 'trackBy' to explicitly tell angular which ones to re-render?

Comment: If object identity is enough to uniquely identify all items in the collection, then you don't need `trackBy`, otherwise you can tell Angular that it should for example use the items `id` property to identify them, for example to apply add/remove/move animations.
If you replace an item in the collection with a new instance which should be treated as the same entity, then use `trackBy` for Angular to be able to recognize it as the same (by the same `id` property value for example)

Comment: It only works in the example because it's a shallow copy. It depends on how you're editing the list. Using the spread operator and adding an additional element, or even filtering out one element when using `filter` can prevent a rerender because the new array is a shallow copy. Using `reverse` will cause all but one element to rerender! If you reassign the list to be the exact same list of elements, by hardcoding explicitly, everything would rerender without using an effective `trackBy` function.

Answer (score 25):

In addition to Gunter's answer, if you want to know which part of your UI is rendered/re-rendered you can with Chrome (even independent from any lib/framework) :

- Open your debug panel
- Menu (of debug panel) / More tools / Rendering

You should then see the following panel :

[image]

Toggle the `Paint Flashing` option on, and have some fun with your list.
If an area is flashing green, it has been painted / re-painted .

EX : If you take the Plunkr in Gunter's answer : http://plnkr.co/edit/oNm5d4KwUjLpmmu4IM2K?p=preview and toggle the `Paint Flashing` on, add an item to the list and you'll see that previous items do not flash. (which means there's no repaint).

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 10 my whole list of elements was rerendering even when previous items were untouched. I used `trackBy` in my ngFor and it fixed the problem.

You can use it like this `<li *ngFor="let chatMessage of chatMessages; trackBy: trackChatMessage">`

And then in your .ts file add function trackChatMessage that returns unique value string.

```
trackChatMessage(index: number, chatMessage: ChatMessage) {
return chatMessage.id;
}
```