# Rendering large nested objects [Angular + Ngrx]

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, reducers, ngrx-store

**Question**
I got a large nested array with several layer of nested children. The object I get back from API is flat, based on ParentId I can know the parent.

In my HTML I want to loop through every object and show it children.

Does any one have a freaky way to write createSelector and a way to select a state at every loop stage in the HTML, so that why I update a nested child, it does not re-render the whole HTML, but only re-render the object that was updated.

I've looked at Angular material table way of doing, trying to see if anyone else has a concept or a way of doing this.

App information:

- Framework: Angular 5 universal
- Statment mgmt: Ngrx
- Backend: Node + swagger

My API call returns a large array with type of object:

```
{
  "id": "299999999"
  "parentId": "5ad4d",
  "body": "string",
  "type": "test"
}
```

Every object has a parentID, that lets know what child is below what child object.

I am storing everything in the list in my state. As you see the list has 3 nested children, but I may have nested children around 20 levels deep.

```
interface AppState {
  list: [
{
  "id": "299999999"
  "parentId": "5ad4d",
  "body": "string",
  "type": "test"
}
{
  "id": "2abc"
  "parentId": "299999999",
  "body": "string",
  "type": "test"
}
{
  "id": "2abcd"
  "parentId": "299999999",
  "body": "string",
  "type": "test"
}
{
  "id": "2abcde"
  "parentId": "299999999",
  "body": "string",
  "type": "test"
}
{
  "id": "2abcde"
  "parentId": "6dda4",
  "body": "string",
  "type": "test"
}
{
  "id": "2abcdefg"
  "parentId": "2abcde",
  "body": "string",
  "type": "test"
}
{
  "id": "23sadasd"
  "parentId": "2abcde",
  "body": "string",
  "type": "test"
}
{
  "id": "12asdasd"
  "parentId": "2abcde",
  "body": "string",
  "type": "test"
}
];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to re-render the whole list (which is a good thing), you don't have a lot of choice.

Trying to have a memoized selector is a good way but it's not enough.

The first thing you should do is define the `trackBy` function within your ngFor loop. The `trackBy` function will take an object as param and you should return something to identify this resource in a unique way, for example by returning it's ID.

Like that, Angular will not re-render the whole list.

I've made an explanation how to make sure it's not re-rendered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42246895/2398593

Comment: you are amazing Maxime ! Thank you

Comment: :) glad it helped!