# Angular 5, component is being initialized with no reason

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following problem-

component A:

```
<!-- LIST OF URLs-->
<exl-file-list  
  *ngIf="hasLinks()"
  listTitle="Added links:"
  [expandable]="editableFiles"
  expandAllButton="Edit metadata"
  (edit)="onLinkEdit($event)"
  (expandAll)="allLinksEditable = !allLinksEditable"
  (removeAll)="onRemoveAllLinks()">

  <!-- URL items -->
  <exl-file-list-item
    *ngFor="let link of depositFormDataService.mainForm.value.links let index = index"
    [item]="link"
    [index]="index"
    (remove)="onLinkRemove($event)"
    (edit)="onLinkEdit($event, index)">

    <!-- metadata of each URL -->
    **<esp-deposit-link-metadata
    [index]="index">
    </esp-deposit-link-metadata>**

  </exl-file-list-item>
</exl-file-list>
```

component B- esp-deposit-link-metadata:

```
<div class="metadata-container">
  <mat-form-field class="hasnt-underline">
    <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
    <textarea 
      matInput 
      [(ngModel)]="description" 
      **(ngModelChange)="onChangeDescription()" 
      ** #textarea placeholder="Describe the link" 
      matTextareaAutosize></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

`onChangeDescription` method, updated my `formGroup` in `depositFormDataService.mainForm.links`

```
onChangeDescription(){
  this.depositFormDataService
    .updateLinkDescription(this.index,this.description);
}
```

it's content:

```
updateLinkDescription(index, description){
  const link = this.links.at(index) as FormGroup;
  link.setControl('description', new FormControl(description));
}
```

depositFormDataService.mainForm holds the links as FormArray.
link is an object with three formControls that one of them is 'description'.

Each time that `onChangeDescription()` is called the `constructor`s of `exl-file-list-item` and `esp-deposit-link-metadata` are called and all the view is refreshed, and I have no reason why.

Comment: Thanks! regarding "[(ngModel)]="description" (ngModelChange)="onChangeDescription()" " comment you gave me before- if I write [ngModel], the description field doesn't update at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you make any changes in `depositFormDataService.mainForm.value.links`, Angular detect changes and it renders the content again.

Since you have used the both of those component inside `*ngFor="let link of depositFormDataService.mainForm.value.links`, it will re-initialized the component.

### in ts

```
trackByLink = (index: number, link : any) => link.url; //check if you have `url` if not then you other unique property.
```

### in html

```
`*ngFor="let link of depositFormDataService.mainForm.value.links ; trackBy:trackByLink `
```

Comment: Although I saw this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244690/does-ngfor-directive-re-render-whole-array-on-every-mutation?fbclid=IwAR0a3Z1RwdnEC843XL-5ECqFnEEYD6_zK1vM7dhFl50V2xsza-zoyF3mTj8
According to it, it should not render the content again.

Comment: Its difficult to tell the exact issue without looking at your entire code however you can fix it by using `trackBy`. Updated my answer.

Comment: By adding the "track by" the component will not be re-initialized?

Comment: Yes, it will not. This way we are telling the if the link is same as before and no re-iteration is required.