# angular 4 add img from right to left onclick

Tags: html, css, angular

I am working with angular 4. My functionality of adding flag is completed, but 
the flags are appearing from left to right.

What I want is that images should be appeared from right to left, on clicking button.

```
<div class="padding-10px" *ngFor="let flag of addedlanguage">
    <img class="flag" [src]="flag" />
</div>
```

I am getting flags from an array.

Comment: When you say `from right to left` you mean your images should be inverted, or you mean the last image added should be on the left ?

Comment: _What I want is that images should be appeared from right to left, on clicking button._ Do you mean that the img's should be animated from right to left?

Comment: yes i mean that last image should be on the left  and should be animated 
 from right to left  @Brampage

Comment: @RajRana Take a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48203556/1265945), if you want a transition/animatino of your images take a look at this [plunker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37217476/1265945), and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217314/how-can-i-animate-ngfor-in-angular).

Comment: yes last image should be on left @trichetriche

Comment: What you want ? An animation or just reverse the images with a flick ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want animations, here is the code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <div class="padding: -10px" *ngFor="let flag of addedlanguage.reverse()">
      <img class="flag" style="position: relative;" [src]="flag" [@flagAnimation]="flag" />
    </div>
  `,
  animations: [
    trigger('flagAnimation', [
      state('*', style({
        opacity: 1,
        left: '*',
      })),
      state('void',   style({
        opacity: 0,
        left: '100px',
      })),
      transition(':enter', animate('100ms ease-out')),
      transition(':leave', animate('100ms ease-in'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class MyComponent {/* ... */}
```

this will align your images to the right, an animate them when they appear.

Comment: images should appear from right to left  ,   means the image added first should at right and last image  added should appear at  left corner

Comment: Then feel free to edit my post and let me know when you're done, so that I can accept it !

Comment: Oh, great then :D

Answer (score 0):

try `addedlanguage.reverse()` in the component.ts file where you are getting all flags

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) the array.

Like this:

```
<div class="padding-10px" *ngFor="let flag of addedlanguage.reverse()">
    <img class="flag" [src]="flag" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float` property in css to align items from left to right and vice-versa.

In your code , you can have a class named rightToLeft

```
.rightToLeft{
   float:right;
 }
```

Then add this class to your div like this

```
    <button (click)="btnFlag=!btnFlag"></button>
    <div class="padding-10px" [ngClass]={'righttoLeft':btnFlag} *ngFor="let flag of addedlanguage">
      <img class="flag" [src]="flag" />
    </div>
```

> Create a variable `btnFlag:boolean` in your component.ts file.

More on floats :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Visit for demo : https://jsfiddle.net/avinash2618/aotpaeuk/

Comment: thanks with the help of  this demo i maded few change and i got it